# What happens when update_all fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There is *update_all* method in RoR

And what does it return if it *update_all* fails? will it raise an exception?

For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  users = User.active
  users.update_all avatar: 'blablablb'
end
```

Comment: `update_all` skips ActiveRecords's normal validations and callbacks. You're basically inserting the query straight into the DB. The only error `update_all` returns is if you leave the attributes empty (no argument). Any errors or exceptions would likely come from `Arel`. You should try running `update_all` with invalid information and seeing what it returns.

Comment: I mean what it there is error in db?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Try it. If you're unsure about the data going into `update_all`, I advise against using it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`update_all` is one of many methods that skip validations and callbacks. So any ActiveRecord validations simply won't be run when calling `update_all`.

However, if the `update_all` call doesn't conform to a constraint at the database level, or otherwise triggers an exception in your database, then ActiveRecord will throw a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` exception and will break from the `update_all` without returning a value, like any other exception.

Other ActiveRecord methods that skip validations include:

- decrement!
- decrement_counter
- increment!
- increment_counter
- toggle!
- touch
- update_attribute
- update_column
- update_counters